# Desired capability not working in latest appium

Tags: appium, appium-android, desiredcapabilities

Desiredcapabilities not supporting in latest appium version(io.appium > 5.0.0).Can you please suggest alternative for the desiredcapability to automate android App

I am using latest version of appium https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/7.0.0.Desired capability is working less than <5.0.0 version

Comment: thats not the truth. paste your code for driver initialization and clarify what doe it mean "Desired capability not working".

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading both seleniumhq along with io.appium has solved this issue Earlier when I upgrade only io.appium below line was throwing error.

`DesiredCapabilities capabilities = capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();`